# How to get access to store from action in VueJS?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Im using VueJS and Vuex. I have the userid into the store, this way:
[vuex screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKVpL.png)

And i try pass the userid to a fetch, but vuejs return error

> ([Vue warn]: Error in created hook: "TypeError: this.$store is
>   undefined")

```
import { LOAD_APPOINTMENTS } from './types'

export default {
  loadProducts ({ commit }) {
    var user = this.$store.state.user.userid
    fetch('api/appointments/' + user)
      .then((result) => {
        return result.json()
      })
      .then((appointments) => {
        commit(LOAD_APPOINTMENTS, appointments)
      })
      .catch(er => {
        console.log(er)
      })
  }
}
```

Comment: How/where do you call `loadProducts` and also what is the file location of the script that you have provided? Is it some kind of `.js` file which just exports that function?

Comment: the script that i have provided is action.js and i call loadProducts in App.Vue. This way:
<script>
export default {
  name: 'App',
  created () {
    this.$store.dispatch('loadProducts')
  }
}
</script>

Comment: Is this action part of the `user` module or the store root?

Comment: @Phil No, i have two store modules (user and products) the module user load the userid and username into vuex store, products fetch from api and load the products for that user in vuex store

Comment: So which module is this action in?

Comment: I believe you are looking for something similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41534412/how-to-get-vuex-state-from-a-javascript-file-instead-of-a-vue-component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, when referencing the store within `vuex` files:

1. `context.state` instead of `this.$store.state`.
2. `context` for all of the `this.$store`. So, `context.commit` and `context.dispatch`.

Second, the `loadProducts` needs to be rewritten as an `action` [per docs](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html#actions).

Third, `loadProducts` needs to incorporate the `context` as a parameter:

```
actions: {
  loadProducts (context) {
    ...
    context.commit(...)
    ...
  }
}
```

As @phil has mentioned in this thread, it is important to view the documentation entirely, as this single answer will get you on the way to debugging the problem, but there might be multiple more problems showing up (e.g. `fetch` errors, file structure errors, component/App level errors).

Comment: I enjoy feedback. If this question was helpful or solved the problem, please upvote and/or accept :)

Comment: Thanks! but it does not work. Now Vuejs return context is not defined :(, sorry is my first vuejs app

Comment: @feli I recommend you read the documentation carefully ~ https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html#actions

Comment: FYI, it should be `loadProducts ({ commit, state })` or just `loadProducts (context)`

Comment: Actions are passed the `context` as their first arg. This `context` has properties `state` and `getters` as well as functions `commit` and `dispatch`. It is commonly destructured using `({ state, getters, commit, dispatch })`, picking only the properties required

Comment: @Phil thanks, I got it now. I messed up my keywords in my brain's RAM, and was thinking `commit` was something OP had declared seeing it defined that way.

Comment: To explain your question about OP's code, I suspect they have something like `import actions from 'path/to/that/file.js'` and then `new Vuex.Store({ state, getters, mutations, actions })`